# Inheritance in LinkedList

Tags: java

For my master thesis, I'm having some problems with my Java code and I'm not really quite sure, why I am having that error message (right now)...

Basically, I have an inheritance package as shown below :

[image: Inheritance Package]

IdentifiersTable class is based on a HashMap < String, LinkedList < InfoIdentifiersTable>>.

My inheritance begins with the classe InfoIdentifiersTable.

So, the class Type,InfoType and Function extends to InfoIdentifiersTable.

Var extends to InfoType -  and - Bool,Sequence,Int,Array,Set extends to Var class.

And I'm having a problem to use these inheritance with my linked list in IdentifiersTable as shown below :
[image]

Which i don't really quite understand why ...

But doing that :
[image]

That error doesn't appear anymore ... Is there any reason for that error message ?

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: I can't post all the codes unfortunately .... It's a big project and beside there is some confidential code... That is one reason i didn't post everything ! But if you have some troubles with anything, ask me ! :)

Comment: You don't need to post all of your code, you just need a *minimal example* which reproduces the problem. In this case, the only code you need is `Type Integer = new Type(0, 1); new LinkedList<InfoIdentifiersTable>(integer);`

Comment: It is only a normal class which extends to InfoIdentifiersTables (No tricky parts) but our friends answered already ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedList impl. List interface and is part of Collection Framework. So it defines two constructor. Empty one and one with an initial collection.

Look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList(java.util.Collection)

But passing a single Value is not possible in the constructor and that is your only error.

Your second approach is simple and useful and I would keep it. Otherwise you would need to wrap your single "integer" value in a Collection to pass it to the LinkedList constructor, which is nonesense ;)

Comment: Okay ! :) Yeah i saw the definition of LinkedList, that's why i wanna try my first approach ! But as i couldn't make it, i wanna understand why it wasn't possible to do it !

Comment: Because a single value is not a collection.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList in JDK has two constructors
`LinkedList()` 
and 
`LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c)`. 
You are attempting to pass in a single element into the constructor, that's causing the error.

Comment: So... I can't pass only one single element to the constructor basically ?

Comment: You can, but you would have to convert it to a list first. You can use `Collections.singletonList()` or `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: Okay ! :) I think I will stay with @Rene M. answer ! :) Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

[`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) has two constructors:

- `LinkedList()` - Constructs an empty list.
- `LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c)` - Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Neither of these constructors take an individual element and instantiate the collection as you are trying to do.

If you want to populate a list in the constructor then you can use the second constructor suppling a list generated by [`Arrays.asList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```
this.idTable.put( "integer", new LinkedList<>( Arrays.asList( integer ) ) );
```

(However, note that there will be a small perfomance hit as it will create an array-backed list to populate the linked list)